# How to get result of BoilerPipe extraction in HTML instead of plain text

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, web-scraping, boilerpipe

I'm using the following code to extract the textual contents from the web pages, my app is hosted on Google App Engine and works exactly like [BoilerPipe Web API](http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/). The problem is that I can only get the result in plain text format. I played around the library to find a work around, but I couldn't find a method to display the result in HTML. What I am trying to have is to include a option like HTML (extract mode) as in the original BoilerPipe Web API [here](http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/).

This is the code I'm using for extracting the plain text.

```
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        String urlString = request.getParameter("url");
        String listOUtput = request.getParameter("OutputType");
        String listExtractor = request.getParameter("ExtractorType");
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        switch (listExtractor) {
            case "1":
                String mainArticle = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);
                out.println(mainArticle);
                break;
            case "2":
                String fullArticle = KeepEverythingExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);
                out.println(fullArticle);
                break;
        }
    } catch (BoilerpipeProcessingException e) {
        out.println("Sorry We Couldn't Scrape the URL you Entered " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println("Exception thrown");
    }
```

How can I include the feature for displaying the result in HTML form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am using the source code of Boilerpipe, and solve your question with the following code:

```
String urlString = "your url";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URI uri = new URI(urlString);

final HTMLDocument htmlDoc = HTMLFetcher.fetch(url);

final BoilerpipeExtractor extractor = CommonExtractors.DEFAULT_EXTRACTOR;

final HTMLHighlighter hh = HTMLHighlighter.newExtractingInstance();
hh.setOutputHighlightOnly(true);

TextDocument doc;

String text = "";

doc = new BoilerpipeSAXInput(htmlDoc.toInputSource()).getTextDocument();
extractor.process(doc);
final InputSource is = htmlDoc.toInputSource();
text = hh.process(doc, is);

System.out.println(text);
```

[Source](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=de.l3s.boilerpipe.BoilerpipeExtractor)